# How to store Data Protection-keys outside of the docker container?

Tags: docker

I am learning to load a blazor server app on to a docker container (aspnet core 3.0.201). I have successfully loaded the image on the container. I am able to create an app build it but while running the blazor server app, I am getting this kind of warn:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
  Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. 
  Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
```

It's a warning but I know is not a good practice to load the keys on the container so I want to fix the warning. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You can look this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#persisting-keys-when-hosting-in-a-docker-container. Basically you can use Cloud(Azure etc.) or Redis

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The warning which you are getting is because ASP.NET Core DataProtection stores keys in the HOME directory (/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys) so when the container restart keys are lost and this might crash the service.

This can be resolved by persisting key at:

- Persist key at the persistent location (volume) and mount that
  volume to docker container
- Persist key at the external key store like Azure or Redis

More details about ASP.NET DataProtection:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

To mount an external volume (C:/temp-keys) to docker container volume (/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys) using following command

`docker run -d -v /c/temp-keys:/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys container-name`

Also, You need to update your `Starup.cs - ConfigureServices` to configure DataProtection policy

```cs
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"))
                .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                {
                    EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                    ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
                });
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. I have done this and I can see a directory being create don my c drive but the project still stores the keys in a directory of the same name under the project.  do you need to change the Directory info to get the local c drive path?

Comment: The solution allows the persistence of the data outside the container, but by default, DPAPI is used for encryption. DPAPI doesn't work in the Linux containers. The provided UseCryptographicAlgorithms() doesn't help because it is still a suggestion to use DPAPI .  Here is an article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio. For Linux containers, it is recommended  to use X.509 certificate to encrypt keys

Answer (score 6):

In my case I am running local, single-user Blazor server so I wanted the simplest solution possible to get rid of warning. I tried setting logging according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0#logging-dataprotection, i.e:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "None"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And it works.

Comment: This worked for me