# Change TimeZone in Docker (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am new to docker and wish to set `TZ=Australia/NSW` to the [official dotnet core docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet)

I tried adding to `ENV TZ=Australia/NSW` on line 5, but it didn't work.

Please help.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENV TZ=Australia/NSW
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build


WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Application.WebAPI/Application.WebAPI.csproj", "Application.WebAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Application.WebAPI/Application.WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Application.WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "Application.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Application.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Application.WebAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: What are your symptoms that show that it's not working? A quick test of `docker run --rm -e TZ=Australia/NSW mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 date` shows that it should work.

Comment: Hi @HansKilian There is an error that says, `"Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container...."`

Comment: That's just a warning isn't it? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452280/how-to-store-data-protection-keys-outside-of-the-docker-container for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

.NET 7.0 Update:

Works just fine for .net 7 also

[image]

Commands ran:

```
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest bash
```

#### Inside Docker

```
dotnet --version
date
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Australia/NSW /etc/localtime
date
```

Got the output from above screenshot.
The OS version for the aspnet image is Debian GNU/Linux 10

[image: OS Release]

I ran two commands inside the docker container

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Australia/NSW /etc/localtime
date
```

And got the below output:

[image: Output]

You could add this to your `Dockerfile` as part of the Docker build instruction

```
Run ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Australia/NSW /etc/localtime
```

Comment: This does not work with dotnet 6 anymore

Comment: shouldn't it be an operating system thing?

Comment: It works with dotnet 5.0 and it does not work with dotnet 6.0 (same application, same settings, apart from the dotnet version)

Comment: Worked just fine for .NET 7.0 image as well

Comment: not working for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0.14-jammy